# SQLException: query does not return results

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-delete

I am doing a project in Java Swing and using SQLite as my database.
This is the function I wrote for deleting a record from the Room table in my database.

```
public void Delete() {
        String room_code = jTextField5.getText();
        String sql = "DELETE FROM Room WHERE room_code = '" + room_code + "'";
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Room Deleted Successfully");
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Room Code");
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }
```

However, I am met with the following Exception: SQLException: query does not return results.
I have tried to use pst.executeUpdate() as suggested in other answers but it says "int cannot be converted into resultset".

Comment: While Swing components mat be used in the app, this problem is something better sorted in a command line app and therefore nothing to do with Swing. Don't add flags irrelevant to the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DELETE` statement does not return a result set. You should call method [executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--) rather than method `executeQuery`.

Also, you can use place holders with a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Also you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Consider the following code.

```java
public void Delete() {
    String room_code = jTextField5.getText();
    String sql = "DELETE FROM Room WHERE room_code = ?";
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(room_code);
        int count = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (count > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Room Deleted Successfully");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Room Code");
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```